# Load map properties from json in mapbox leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I have drawn a polygon in mapbox using leaflet and I want to change one of its property dynamically.

My code is below:

```
    map.js

    var map = L.map('map').setView([1.3096622448984000, 103.7689017333800], 10);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpandmbXliNDBjZWd2M2x6bDk3c2ZtOTkifQ._QA7i5Mpkd_m30IGElHziw', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'mapbox.light'
    }).addTo(map);
    map.doubleClickZoom.disable();




    // get color depending on population density value
    function getColor(d) {
        return  d > 1000 ? '#4CA64C' :
                d > 500  ? '#6fdc6f' :
                d > 200  ? '#6fdc6f' :
                d > 100  ? '#6fdc6f' :
                d > 50   ? '#6fdc6f' :
                d > 20   ? '#6fdc6f' :
                d > 10   ? '#6fdc6f' :
                           '#FFEDA0';

    }

    function style(feature) {
        return {
            weight: 2,
            opacity: 1,
            color: '#999',
            fillOpacity: 0.7,
            fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.demand)
        };
    }

    var geojson = L.geoJson(campus, {
        style: style,
    }).addTo(map);

    function highlightFeature(e) {
    var layer = e.target;

    layer.setStyle({
        weight: 5,
        color: '#666',
        dashArray: '',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    });


    if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
        layer.bringToFront();
    }

    info.update(layer.feature.properties);

    }
function resetHighlight(e) {
    geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
     info.update();
}
function zoomToFeature(e) {
    map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
    map.doubleClickZoom.disable();
}


function searchText(e,feature)
{
     var layer = e.target;
     var search = {
            'zone': layer.feature.properties.name,
            'zone_id':layer.feature.id
             };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType : 'json',
                    url: "http://dataurl",
                    data: JSON.stringify(search), // Note it is important
                    success :function(result) {
                     // do what ever you want with data
                     //  alert("suc");

                   },
                    error:function(error){
                     //alert("success");
                      }
                });
 }


var lastClickedLayer;
function clickFeature(e) {
    if(lastClickedLayer){
         //  geojson.resetStyle(lastClickedLayer);
        }


    var layer = e.target;
        layer.setStyle({
        weight: 5,
        color: '#800000',
        dashArray: '',
        fillOpacity: 0.7,
        fillColor: getColor(1000)
        });



    lastClickedLayer = layer;
        }

function onMapClick(e,feature) {


    var layer = e.target;
    clickFeature(e);
    $("#grid_name").html(layer.feature.properties.name);

    //layer.bindPopup( '<b>'+layer.feature.properties.name+ '</b><h4><b>Demandsjfh<b></h4>'+ layer.feature.properties.demand);
    searchText(e,feature);
       setDataSet("http://data_url"+layer.feature.id);



}
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
        mouseover: highlightFeature,
        mouseout: resetHighlight,
        //click: zoomToFeature
        click:onMapClick

    });

}

geojson = L.geoJson(campus, {
    style: style,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);

var info = L.control();

info.onAdd = function (map) {
    this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info'); // create a div with a class "info"
    this.update();
    return this._div;
};

// method that we will use to update the control based on feature properties passed
info.update = function (props) {
    this._div.innerHTML = '<h4><b>Zones<b></h4>' +  (props ?
        '<b>' + props.name + '</b><br />'  
        : 'Hover over a zone');

    //props.demand=props.demand+1000;

};


info.addTo(map);
```

My geojson data file will look like 
demand.js
    var campus = {

```
        "type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
{
                        "type": "Feature",
                        "id":"04",
                        "properties": {
                            "name": "cool",
                            "demand":"1000"
                        },
                        "geometry": {
                            "type": "MultiPolygon",
                            "coordinates": [
                                [
                                    [

                                        [103.796,1.33175],[103.795,1.33092],[103.795,1.33032]               

                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        }
                    }                
]};
```

Now I want to change the property  **demand** by loading external JSON value from a URL.

The URL will contain JSON data for demand as

**[{"demand":12}]**

So I only want to change the demand property in the demand.js dynamically.

Comment: do you want to change this for permanently or for now ?Y do you want to change in demand.js ?

Comment: @Pranav MS Instead of having fixed demand property I want to change it dynamically.So the demand will be in the url and if a event occurs it will fetch that particular demand.

Comment: so change the json file through the jquery or JavaScript with corresponding values .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your json  dynamically when document is ready. please gothrough the below code.

**javascript**

```
<script tyep="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {  
        var campus={"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
                    {
                            "type": "Feature",
                            "id":"04",
                            "properties": {
                                "name": "cool",
                                "demand":"1000"
                            },
                            "geometry": {
                                "type": "MultiPolygon",
                                "coordinates": [ [ [ [103.796,1.33175],[103.795,1.33092],[103.795,1.33032]  ] ]  ]
                            }
                        }                
                ]};
                console.log(campus);  
                console.log("1 time demand in console--"+campus['features'][0]['properties']['demand']);
                campus['features'][0]['properties']['demand']=12;
                console.log("2 time demand in console after change--"+campus['features'][0]['properties']['demand']);

     });
</script>
```

**console output**
[image]

Please try this . May this will help you. This is working in my case.